# Improving the performance of rendering hundreds of components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am rendering a list in React Native which currently has about 900 list items. I'm mapping through the list and rendering one component for each item. It currently takes about 3 seconds for React to do this which is unacceptable - I would like it to be near instant. Props are passed to the list item component from the redux store and the list items are nested inside the React Native `ScrollView` Component.

How can I can I increase the performance of rendering these components so there is not such a huge lag?

Here is my `Contacts` component:

```
 class Contacts extends Component {

  renderRegisteredUsers = (contacts) => {
    return contacts.items.map((contact, index) => (
      <ContactListItem
        key={index}
        firstName={contact.user.address_book_name}
        surname={''}
        phoneNumber={contact.user.phone}
        isRegisteredUser={true}
        ccId={contact.user.id}
      />
    ))
  }

  renderContacts = (contacts) => {
    if (contacts) {
      return contacts.map((contact, index) => (
        <ContactListItem
          key={index}
          firstName={contact.firstName}
          surname={contact.surname}
          phoneNumber={contact.phoneNumber}
          isRegisteredUser={false}
        />
      ))
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <Loader />
        </>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>
            Your Contacts Using Fleeting
        </Text>
          {this.renderRegisteredUsers(this.props.user.registeredContacts)}
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>
            Phone Contacts
        </Text>
          {this.renderContacts(this.props.user.parsedContacts)}
        </ScrollView>
      </>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { user } = state;
  return { user }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Contacts);
```

And my `ContactListItem` component:

```
class ContactListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.props.calleeId(this.props.ccId)
    Actions.TimeInput();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: 20, display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
        <Text>
          {this.props.firstName + ' ' + this.props.surname + '                          ' + this.props.phoneNumber}
        </Text>
        <Icon name="adduser" size={40} color="green" style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }} onPress={this.handleOnClick} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  calleeId,
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactListItem);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You can use `PureComponent` instead of `Component`. PureComponent re-renders only when its props change and not re-rendering on each parent re-render. More Information: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

2- Use unique `key`s when you're mapping on your items.

3- You can use `FlatList` instead of `ScrollView`. It supports `Scroll Loading`. You can set a number of initial numbers and render the others on scroll. More Information: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (<Text key={item.key}>{item.key}</Text>);

const getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
  {length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index}
);

const items = [{ key: 'first' }, { key: 'second'}, ...+1000];

function render () => (
  <FlatList
    data={items}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
    initialNumToRender={5}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
    windowSize={10}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using pagination instead- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pagination. If your contacts are coming from an api request, you will have to look into paginating the requests too.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,View,FlatList,} from 'react-native';
import ContactItem from './Pages/widgets/ContactItem'; // https://github.com/garrettmac/react-native-pagination/blob/master/ReactNativePaginationExample/Pages/widgets/ContactItem.js
import faker from 'faker';//assuming you have this.
import _ from 'lodash';
import Pagination,{Icon,Dot} from 'react-native-pagination';//{Icon,Dot} also available



export default class ReactNativePaginationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
      this.state = {
        items: this.props.contacts,
      };
    }
    //create each list item
  _renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (<ContactItem index={item.id}
        onPressItem={this.onPressItem.bind(this)}
        name={item.name}
        avatar={item.avatar}
        description={item.email}
        tag={item.group}
        createTagColor
      />)
    };
    //pressed an item
  onPressItem = (item) => console.log("onPressItem:item ",item);


  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) =>this.setState({viewableItems})

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[s.container]}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.items}
            ref={r=>this.refs=r}//create refrence point to enable scrolling
            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}//map your keys to whatever unique ids the have (mine is a "id" prop)
            renderItem={this._renderItem}//render each item
            onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged.bind(this)}//need this
          />

          <Pagination
            // dotThemeLight //<--use with backgroundColor:"grey"
            listRef={this.refs}//to allow React Native Pagination to scroll to item when clicked  (so add "ref={r=>this.refs=r}" to your list)
            paginationVisibleItems={this.state.viewableItems}//needs to track what the user sees
            paginationItems={this.state.items}//pass the same list as data
            paginationItemPadSize={3} //num of items to pad above and below your visable items
          />
        </View>
      )
  }
};

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // backgroundColor:"grey",//<-- use with "dotThemeLight"
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativePaginationExample', () => App);
```

Comment: Pagination is the correct answer, but you should actually include a brief code example.